# How does change of pressure affect molecular rovibrational bands position and width?

Tags: spectroscopy

Lets say I have $CO_2$ gas chamber with pressure $P_0$. 
How do rotation-vibrational transition bands alter when I change pressure P?
Do they shift or not and why?

Comment: So, what do you think?  How are you approaching the problem? What factors might you need to consider?

Comment: Will you be keeping the temperature constant as you increase the pressure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do shift, but the explanation of this effect is complicated. There are many papers dedicated to pressure shift of spectral lines, even whole books with titles like "Collisional Effects on Molecular Spectra".

If you want to start somewhere, look for the Rautian-Sobelman model. ([google books](http://books.google.ch/books?id=Cj10VClBj9gC&lpg=PA104&ots=H_MvzBKMw_&dq=collisional%20sobel'man&pg=PA104#v=onepage&q=collisional%20sobel'man&f=false))